# Retrieve meta_value from add_comment_meta

Tags: avatar, comment-meta

I have a voting function for comments which needs to display the avatars of the users who voted for a specific comment.
I am having trouble getting the user id of the voter ($supporter). All I seem to get is the user ID of the user who made the comment > I need to get the user ID of the user who voted.

My function:

```
function addServiceSupporter($comment_id, $user_id) {
    add_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'supporting_user', $user_id, false );
}
```

So the $user_id is stored under meta_value in the wp_commentmeta table.

Before this function I have this the following which seems to have a user_id in it.

```
/**
 * After an ajax call try to add the supporter
 */
if (isset($_POST['new_service'])) {
    $new_service_supporter = $_POST['new_service'];
    try {
        addServiceSupporter($new_service_supporter['comment_id'], $new_service_supporter['user_id']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r($e);
    }
    die;
}
```

The call:

```
foreach($supporters as $supporter) {
    $supporting_user = get_comment_meta(get_comment_ID(),'supporting_user', true);
    $avatar = get_avatar($supporting_user, 24 );

    echo $avatar; 
}
```

I also have tried:

```
$avatar = get_avatar($supporting_user, 24 );
```

But that of course gives the avatar of the user currently active on the page.

How do I get the $user_id aka meta_value of this comment_meta?

The result should be:
Comment votes (or likes if you want) by users to the comments of others. 
Then showing the avatars of the people who voted. 
My problem = how to get the user id of the **voters** (not the comment author, not the current user) so I can show the right avatar?

Comment: what is the code before the line `foreach($supporters as $supporter) {` ?

Comment: that would be 
    global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo();

Answer (score 0):

You are saving your data with non-unique key (`false` as last argument), but retrieve it it as singular data (`true` as last argument).

This is likely returning you the *first* voter on comment. You need to retrieve complete array of values and work with it to be operating on complete data.

Comment: Would you know what I should put instead of true? Leaving it empty, or false, or anything else gives met an "Array to string conversion"

Comment: @inTOWN yes, that's the point, without `true` you get array of all values and need to process it to get what you actually want (last value for example)

Comment: Could you please give me an example of who I could solve this? (sorry, this part is not my strongest point)

Comment: @inTOWN still fuzzy on what you are actually trying to do and this is more in realm of basic PHP. Try to update your question with more information.

Comment: I just updated the question. The problem is that I need to get the ID of the voter so I can show the right avatar. Right now I only seem to be capable of getting the ID of the a) Comment author or b) the current user.

Comment: I just updated my question again with the ajax call that adds the voter/supporter. I can see an user_id there, that might be the one I need?

Comment: Please help me with an example of what you said in your answer: "You need to retrieve complete array of values"
My PHP skills are not so well that I know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do was to:

```
$supporters = get_comment_meta(get_comment_ID(),'supporting_user', false);
```

1. Rename $supporting_user to $supporter (just like the foreach)
2. change true into false

Full code:

```
$supporters = get_comment_meta(get_comment_ID(),'supporting_user', false);
foreach($supporters as $supporter) {
$avatar = get_avatar($supporter, 24 );
echo $avatar; 
}
```

Thanks @Rast for trying to help.